# Identifying a Spanish name in old Spanish calligraphy from a birth certificate from 1849

Tags: escritura, identificación-de-término

I have a copy of a birth certificate from 1849. There is **one name** in the certificate that I can't transcribe to any known Spanish name (anything that comes to mind). The document isn't in great condition and the script is hard to read unfortunately.

The picture with the name in question is below. I believe it says `"Don X"` where `X` is of the form `"...t...io"`. In other words, the name ends in `"io"`and it includes a `t`.

[image]

Full page view of the birth certificate in case it helps understand this old Spanish calligraphy.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is out of the scope of this site. I'm not if there is a stack exchange where it would be, though. (*Potentially* a question could be asked dealing with *letras cortesanas* since they were exclusive to Spanish but even then it'd need to be something specific to the writing)

Comment: This absolutely off-topic. Perhaps if you post as an answer what you have so far and highlight what you don't understand your question won't be closed too fast.

Comment: I have some experience translating handwritten documents and, to do that, I first have to understand what the original says. When I don't, I write [illegible]. I think I can understand most of the document. However, while one can understand most of the vocabulary items, it's not so easy when it comes to names, in which case some hard comparison effort with other letters in the document has to be undertaken.

Comment: @walen I was not going to answer. I just let OP know that this requires some effort.

Comment: It is a shame we had to close it but perhaps if the OP can provide some partial translation and guesses at missing words it might become on-topic again.

Comment: Sorry @mdewey I was offline for the last few days. I am rewriting it right away to improve the question and make it be on-topic again.

Comment: @walen Thank you all for your patience. Sorry I was offline (phone access only) for the past few days. I made substantial changes to the question. I hope this helps!

Comment: @Gustavson I updated the question significantly to narrow it down to something I am hoping is on-topic (identification of a Spanish name from that time).

Comment: Thanks @walen. Makes sense. In my mind, Spanish caligraphy/names may be on-topic, but I think you could be right that the question isn't there. Let me ask you this instead, If I had a name/word, and wanted to confirm if it's indeed a Spanish name, would that be on-topic?

Comment: good edit. I tried for a while but could not get what that word is. Exactly two lines below it says "y Doña Josefa" and that first part is the same exept for the line on top of the n... so the name you are looking for starts with "Don".

Comment: @Charlie and I have reached un agreement at the chat room :) It says "Don Antonio": Both words are togheter probably because of a mistake of the scribe, which tried to mend it with a knot or big point between both words, which can be mistaken with a lower case letter. Then there is a capital A that seems a lower case T. In the end, you have what seems to be a capital D, but it is actually the curl of a lower case O, a distinctive feature in the scribe handwriting. Finally, if you compare these words to the first two words in the document (clearly Don Antonio), you will see the similarities.

Comment: I agree with the comments before, and with @Alicia (it's definitely "Don Antonio"). Nonetheless, have you tried asking in [Genealogy.SE]?

Comment: Voting to reopen and I have to say I'm very impressed with the analysis provided by @Alicia.  I would like to see this put into an Answer. // About my vote to reopen.  I am certainly one of those people who like to close questions that show no effort, and I also get annoyed with people who sneak in answers under the radar by putting them in comments, since I do agree with the general principle of Let's avoid training participants to ask poorly posed questions by going ahead and answering them anyway!  However, I see no indication of laziness on the part of the OP in this case.

Comment: Regarding whether it's off topic for reasons having nothing to do with effort shown -- here's my reasoning: as was demonstrated, there are regular participants on this site who have the knowledge, expertise, experience, intellectual curiosity, etc., etc., to sink their teeth into a problem like this and SOLVE the heck out of it.  More power to them. Note, I don't think there's much danger of setting a trend and getting inundated with questions of exactly this type.

Comment: @walen - Are there any other sites in this network with experts in these three examples?  Tango and prime factors yes.

Comment: @walen - Well, if that works, great.  "Identificar o descifrar un término de acuerdo a una pronunciación no clara o mal recordada, una memoria vaga, mala caligrafía o audio, u otras situaciones que hacen difícil comprender con claridad el término usado."  Wow, that's quite a catch-all!

Comment: @aparente001 Related discussion on Meta: [Should we accept questions about identifying words in texts?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3238/1674)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the Spanish language. We are not manuscript decipherers.

Comment: http://firstblacks.org/en/summaries/paleography-tool/ AND: http://spanishpaleographytool.org/

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's quite simple to find the name by analyzing the rest of the document:

| [image] |
| --- |
| Doña Josefa (see **DOÑ**a) |
| [image] |
| Don Antonio (see **Antonio**) |
| [image] |
| Don Antonio |